# Select column value based on multiple conditions XML

Tags: python, xml, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find and click on the second sibling of an element that is identified by two conditions using `By.XPATH` in the following table:

[image]

`Type == "Renewal"` and `Seq# == 1`, but I cannot seem to make the two conditions work:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//td[@text()='Renewal' and text()='1']/followingsibling::td[2]/a").click()
```

Comment: Did your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75441790/7429447) got resolved?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium It did, I just accepted the answer.

Comment: Yeap, I saw you accepted an answer. Did you happen to checkout which answer was more appropiate as per your requirements amog the multiple answers published against your question?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element associated with *Type == "Renewal"* and *Seq# == 1* you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath* and *`following`*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='Renewal']//following::td[contains(., '1')]//following::td[1]").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`following-sibling`*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='Renewal']//following-sibling::td[contains(., '1')]//following-sibling::td[1]").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

Comment: None of the options you suggested work, I still get a ```NoSuchElement``` error.

Comment: @ArthurLanglois There was a bug in the code, corrected it. retest and let me know the status.